# Return all contents within an object

Tags: go

I am very new to Go, so I am sorry for that noob question.

In JavaScript `console.log(window)` returns all objects inside of `window`. In PHP `var_dump(new DateTime())` returns all objects inside of `DateTime()`.

Is there a function in Go that will return all objects from a given object? For example `Println` should be returned if `fmt` is given.

Comment: `fmt` is a package, not an object, so there's no way to list it's contents. I think you're looking godoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing `go doc fmt` in a terminal to produce a description of the "fmt" package and a listing of the functions it exports, or referring to the [`fmt` package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) at https://golang.org. In go, as in most other static/compiled languages, users are expected to refer to *documentation* (or *docs*) which describe the programming language and its libraries. Contrast this to some [dynamic/scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language), which often make it easy to query any object to discover its usable properties.

At runtime, you can get a helpful printout of any arbitrary *value* by using the `%#v` formatting verb to produce a go syntax representation of the value, e.g.

```
xs := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Printf("OK: xs=%#v\n", xs)
// OK: xs=[]int{1, 2, 3}
```

Note that the package "fmt" is not a *value* in the go language so it cannot be printed at runtime as such.

Answer (score 2):

In Go is possible does something similar, but don't work for all.

```
func main() {

    //arrays
    a := []int{1,2,3,4}
    fmt.Printf("%v\r\n", a)         //print [1 2 3 4]

    //maps
    b := map[string]int{
          "a":1,
          "b":2,
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\r\n", b)        //print map[a:1 b:2]

    //structs
    c := struct{
          A int
          B int
    }{1,2}
    d := struct{
          C struct{
              A int 
              B int
          }
          D int
    }{c,2}
    fmt.Printf("%v\r\n", d)        //print {{1 2} 2}
}
```

See in: https://play.golang.org/p/vzlCsOG497h

If you pass *fmt* occurs error because it is a package. The error is:

```
Error: use of package fmt without selector
```

I hope this helps (too)!

Answer (score 1):

#### GO [OOP](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language), & [inheritance](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance)

Go does not have objects, but we do have custom types and interfaces that we can attach attributes, functions and other types to.

What specifically are you trying to do? If you're looking for a `var_dump`:

#### USING [`fmt.Println`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println)

```
someErr := fmt.Errorf("custom type error")
fmt.Println(someErr)
```

`Println` formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output.

#### USING [`fmt.Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf)

```
someErr := fmt.Errorf("custom type error")
fmt.Printf("This is an error:%v A num: %v A str", someErr, 19, "Stackoverflow")
```

`Printf` formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard output.

#### USING [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)

```
someErr := fmt.Errorf("custom type error")
// someStr now contains the string formatted as shown below
someStr := fmt.Sprintf("This is an error:%v A num: %v A str", someErr, 19, "Stackoverflow")
```

`Sprintf` formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string.

Here is an example of my personal preference when outputting var data:
https://play.golang.org/p/8dpeE-fray_J

**I hope this helps!**

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!